# JS Контекст вызова this внутри функции внутри метода объекта

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'cc',
  trade: function() {
    console.log(this.name); //cc
  }
};

obj.trade();


var obj = {
  name: 'cc',
  trade: function() {
    console.log(this); //name, trade
    (function() {
      console.log(this); //window, в этом и вопрос, почему, 
      //ведь эта функция выполняется внутри метода объекта
    })();
  }
};

obj.trade();
```

Почему `this` у функции, которая находится внутри метода `trade` объекта `obj`, равен `window`, а не `obj`?

Comment: Код -- текстом! (Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что важно не то, где функция находится, а как вызывается:

```
(function() {
  console.log(this);
}).call(this);
```